# 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hey guys I am having issues with my app opening the flash cards future I have added to my app. I have put in when you click on the flashcards button its supposed to open the flashcards class however when you click on the flashcards button I get a this app has stopped error. heres the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.llamacorp.equate, PID: 4491
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.llamacorp.equate/gabilheri.com.flashcards.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
at gabilheri.com.flashcards.DrawerLayoutActivity.onCreate(DrawerLayoutActivity.java:43)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

heres the main activity:

```
package gabilheri.com.flashcards;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import com.llamacorp.equate.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import gabilheri.com.flashcards.database.MyDbHelper;
import gabilheri.com.flashcards.fragments.DefaultFragment;
import gabilheri.com.flashcards.fragments.FragmentCategories;
import gabilheri.com.flashcards.fragments.FragmentDecks;
import gabilheri.com.flashcards.fragments.FragmentFlashCardViewer;
import gabilheri.com.flashcards.fragments.FragmentFlashCardsList;
import gabilheri.com.flashcards.fragments.FragmentNewCategory;
import gabilheri.com.flashcards.fragments.FragmentNewDeck;
import gabilheri.com.flashcards.fragments.FragmentNewFlashCard;
import gabilheri.com.flashcards.navDrawer.NavDrawerAdapter;
import gabilheri.com.flashcards.navDrawer.NavDrawerItem;


public class MainActivity extends DrawerLayoutActivity {

    private static final String TAG_ACTIVE_FRAGMENT = "fragment_active";

    // We use this to know which of the items has been selected.
    // We name the items so we know which one is which.
    // For the fragments that will be OUTSIDE of the drawer layout we use negative numbers so we avoid a conflict.
    public static final int FLASHCARDS_VIEWER = -6;
    public static final int FLASHCARDS_FRAG = -5;
    public static final int DECKS_FRAG = -4;
    public static final int NEW_FLASHCARD_FRAG = -3;
    public static final int NEW_DECK_FRAG = -2;
    public static final int NEW_CATEGORY_FRAG = -1;
    public static final int CATEGORIES_FRAG = 0;
    public static final int SETTINGS_FRAG = 1;
    private DefaultFragment activeFragment = null;

    private NavDrawerAdapter mNavDrawerAdapter;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private HashMap<Integer, String> fragmentTitles;
    private Bundle currentBundle;


    @Override
    public void init() {
        // Retrieve the typedArray from the XML. Notice the weird Syntax "obtain"
        TypedArray navIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_titles); // Retrieve the titles
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>(); // Initialize the ArrayList

        // Now let's add add items to the ArrayList of NavDrawer items.
        for(int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i], navIcons.getDrawable(i)));
        }
        // An typed array can be recycled to avoid waste of System Resources. In our case it wouldn't matter because we only have 2 items.. but is still a good practice.
        navIcons.recycle();

        mNavDrawerAdapter = new NavDrawerAdapter(this, navDrawerItems);

        // We need a HashMap to map the Title of the fragments that are not on our Nav Drawer
        fragmentTitles = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        fragmentTitles.put(NEW_CATEGORY_FRAG, getString(R.string.new_cat_title));
        fragmentTitles.put(NEW_DECK_FRAG, getString(R.string.new_deck_title));
        fragmentTitles.put(NEW_FLASHCARD_FRAG, getString(R.string.new_flashcard_title));
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreFragment(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //Restore the fragment's instance
            activeFragment = (DefaultFragment) getFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "activeFragment");
    }

    @Override
    public void displayView(int position, Bundle fragmentBundle) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); // Get the fragmentManager for this activity
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        switch (position) {
            case CATEGORIES_FRAG:
                activeFragment = new FragmentCategories(); // Set the ActiveFragment to our selected item on the list
                clearBackStack(); // Clear the back stack to avoid back presses bugs
                break;
            case SETTINGS_FRAG:
                break;
            case NEW_CATEGORY_FRAG:
                activeFragment = new FragmentNewCategory();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); // null = name of the fragment on the stack.
                break;
            case NEW_DECK_FRAG:
                activeFragment = new FragmentNewDeck();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                break;
            case DECKS_FRAG:
                activeFragment = new FragmentDecks();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); // null = name of the fragment on the stack.
                break;
            case FLASHCARDS_FRAG:
                activeFragment = new FragmentFlashCardsList();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                break;
            case NEW_FLASHCARD_FRAG:
                activeFragment = new FragmentNewFlashCard();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                break;
            case FLASHCARDS_VIEWER:
                activeFragment = new FragmentFlashCardViewer();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if(activeFragment != null) {
            if(fragmentBundle != null) {
                currentBundle = fragmentBundle;
                activeFragment.setArguments(fragmentBundle);
            }

            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.alpha_in, R.animator.alpha_out, // Animations for the fragment in...
                            R.animator.alpha_in, R.animator.alpha_out) // Animations for the fragment out...
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, activeFragment, TAG_ACTIVE_FRAGMENT) // We then replace whatever is inside FrameLayout to our activeFragment
                    .commit(); // Commit the change
            // update selected item and title
            if(position >= 0) {
                getDrawerList().setItemChecked(position, true); // We now set the item on the drawer that has been cliced as active
                getDrawerList().setSelection(position); // Same concept as above...
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]); // We not change the title of the Action Bar to match our fragment.
            } else {
                if(fragmentBundle == null) {
                    setTitle(fragmentTitles.get(position)); // We not change the title of the Action Bar to match our fragment.
                } else {
                    setTitle(fragmentBundle.getString(MyDbHelper.TITLE));
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(getLogTag(), "Error creating fragment"); // if the fragment does not create we Log an error.
        }
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to change the log tag string;
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public String getLogTag() {
        return "MainActivity";
    }

    @Override
    protected BaseAdapter getAdapter() {
        return mNavDrawerAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "activeFragment", activeFragment);
    }
}
```

EDIT Here's The DrawerLayoutActivity:

```
package gabilheri.com.flashcards;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.llamacorp.equate.R;


public abstract class DrawerLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    private final String LOG_TAG = getLogTag();

    /**
     * Nav Drawer stuff
     */
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle, mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayout());

        // Enabling action bar app and Icon , and behaving it as a toggle button.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        /**
         * Drawer Layout stuff
         */
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerListener());

        init();

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(getAdapter());

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, // Nav drawer Icon
                R.string.app_name, // Nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // Nav drawer close
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            restoreFragment(savedInstanceState);
        } else if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            displayView(0, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstance has occurred
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Drawer listener.
     */
    private class DrawerListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            /**
             * A handler with a postDelayed is used so it only changes fragments once the drawer is
             * already closed. This can be adjusted if the timing is not right.
             * Similar behavior that most Google apps offers.
             */
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    displayView(position, null);
                }
            }, 300);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to define what clicking on the drawer will do.
     *
     * @param position
     *          The position of the clicked item
     * @param fragmentBundle
     *          A bundle in case something needs to be passed to a specific fragment
     */
    public abstract void displayView(int position, Bundle fragmentBundle);

    /**
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */
    public abstract void restoreFragment(Bundle savedInstanceState);

    /**
     * Any specific initializations should go here.
     */
    public abstract void init();

    /**
     * Override this method to change the log tag string;
     * @return
     */
    public String getLogTag() {
        return "DrawerActivity";
    }

    /**
     * Override this method in case of need for a different list colors, etc..
     * Should use same Id's to avoid confusion
     * @return
     *      The Activity layout for this drawer activity
     */
    private int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.drawer_activity;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the drawer toggle
     * @return
     *      The drawer toggle for this activity
     */
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle getDrawerToggle() {
        return mDrawerToggle;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *      The List used by the drawer
     */
    public ListView getDrawerList() {
        return mDrawerList;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *      The Drawer Layout used by this activity
     */
    public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
        return mDrawerLayout;
    }

    /**
     *
     * Method to be Overriden that will return an Adapter that extends Base Adapter
     * The adapter will them be used by the Drawer Layout
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected abstract BaseAdapter getAdapter();

    /**
     * Handy method to clear the back stack. We want to do this to avoid back stack bugs.
     */
    public void clearBackStack() {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
            manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // If the back stack is empty we let android handle the back button
        if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // Otherwise we remove it from the back stack and the framework will handle the
            // fragment change for us :)
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

and the build.grade:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.llamacorp.equate"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1 // The version Code is used by the Play Store. Every time an update is pushed to the play store the version code should be updated as well.
        versionName "1.0" // Visible version name for the users on the Play Store
        testApplicationId "com.llamacorp.equate.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Will compile all the Libraries inside the 'libs' folder
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
    // We will be using the support library for the Drawer layout
    // Very good library to use cards
    compile files('lib/achartengine.jar')
    compile files('lib/bsh-core-2.0b4.jar')
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.9.1'
}
```

I know they are a bunch of posts on this error already but none that relate to this certain case I have tried the suggestions the other forms have suggested and none of them worked for me so  any help would be amazing

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is your activity theme?

Comment: The crash is in `gabilheri.com.flashcards.DrawerLayoutActivity`, in its `onCreate()` method. We cannot help you with that, as you have not published the code for `gabilheri.com.flashcards.DrawerLayoutActivity`. Consider editing your question to provide the code referenced in the stack trace.

Comment: DrawerLayoutActivity has been added to the question sorry about that

Comment: Why aren't you using AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: As Jedil asks, what theme are you using for this activity? Something about the theme is blocking the native action bar, which is why you are getting `null` when you try to work with it.

Comment: @Jedil and CommonsWare I have not declared any theme for this activity in my manifest but the Base application theme in styles is: style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" does that help you out? please let me know

Comment: That is very strange, as that theme has an action bar. Try temporarily setting the activity theme directly to `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` and see if that gets you past this error. If it does, then there is something about `AppTheme` that is blocking the action bar. If `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` also fails, then I am out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: thanks for the feedback you want me to put the @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar in the manifest for the mainactivity correct?

Comment: just wanted you to know that did not fix it if anyone else has any suggestions please feel free to comment